# clone/copy/create a new skype group from another skype group with removal of some of the participants

Tags: skype, clone, copy, transfer

I want to create a new Skype group with almost all the participants from another Skype group (~100 participants); how can I do that, without noting down each colleague's id and, latter, add him/her in the new group?

Context: I want to make a surprise to a leaving senior colleague from our team. I would like to create another Skype group with all the persons except him.

(I'm using Skype 8.100.0.203 on macOsVentura 13.4.1)

Answer (score 0):

The only aid available in Skype is to use the
`/showmembers` chat command in the group.

This command retrieves a list of everyone in the chat with Skype ID,
name, and role (Admin or User).

I don't use Skype, so cannot advise whether the format of this list
is useful.

Reference :
[What chat commands are available in Skype?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34929/what-chat-commands-are-available-in-skype)

Comment: ok. How do I delete the message displayed after entering /showmembers? Some might ... freak out seeing this in the main chat

Comment: Now this is weird! :) After exiting Skype, the list of members is no longer displayed

Comment: I think it's only visible to you.

Comment: thank you, @harrymc ! :)

Comment: your answer is very useful in the first part of the process (i.e. extracting the information) ... the second part of the process, it's still very laborious manual work (i.e. inserting each contact by hand, choosing the right one ids from the suggested list of contacts). Do you happen to know how could that part be simplified too?

Comment: I don't know the format of the text you copied. A good text editor that supports regex could help.

Comment: I agree with you: the problem is not how the information you get looks like. The big problem is how you insert that data (processed or not) into a new group. (I copied the data from the application, and in this version, all I had to remove are 3 spaces before each id and the user type (admin/normal user) which any text editor without regex can do without any problem) How do I put all these ids into a new group? I'd tried to paste them and leave a comma and a space between them, but that doesn't work

Comment: in conclusion, in order to copy/clone, you need (1) to read data (this is well done by your answer) but then you have to (2) write data. I don't know how to do, in an efficient way, the writing process especially for large groups (with many users)

Comment: It seems like there was once a [method](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/how-do-i-save-and-transfer-skype-contacts/08a3bf82-21f7-4ec5-a8a9-a5d43ca9206f) for importing, but I don't see it in my Skype. If you don't see it in yours or on the web then it no longer exists. I have seen on Apple someone who has written a script that manipulated the Skype interface for that, clicking and entering text as required. That's also possible on Windows, but not something I can do as I don't use Skype.

Comment: nor the application or the web have the Contacts menu anymore; I'd tried on the web version to write some JavaScript code in the browsers' console to do that, but I wasn't very successful.

Comment: On Windows I would use AutoHotKey.